# After CB uninstall can not use joomla 1.5. login it take user to a blank page?

Tags: joomla1.5

After I removed/uninstalled CB 1.4 from my joomla 1.5.9 site as well as all jos_comprofiler files. the mod_login do not work nor does the registration. When I check the error log it sais file not found Kunena/media but I do not use Kunena on my site however the component was there I deleted it but login still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

It is a module or plugin conflict.Try disabling modules or plugin one by one & check if it works..If you have installed k2 then k2-user plugin must be the culprit.